# Open popup page using jquery click()

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, popup

I want to open or show up popup page using java script in input text :

```
<input class="addpopup" type="text" name="address" id="address"></input>
<script>
    $(".addpopup").click(function () {
        $(this).page('#popupAddfix');
    });
</script>
```

And popup code :

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupAddfix">
  <form>
    <h3>Your Address</h3>
    <label >Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="addfix" id="fix" value=""/>

    <button type="submit" >Save</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

But it is not opening a popup. How do I make this happen ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To open popup programmatically, you need to call it using `.popup('open')`. Using any event, e.g. `focus`, `click`, `tap`...etc

> **[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/2fqfV/)**

```
$(document).on('focus', '.addpopup', function() {
 $('#popupAddfix').popup('open');
});
```

Comment: How to open the popup on mouse/finger position?

Comment: Check finger/mouse X & Y position retrieved from the event. Then use `.popup("open")`. @eddywhite